# ODS path is reset by SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas

I added an ODS path statement in the autoexec_usermods.sas on the workspace server like this:

```
ods path mylibrary.templat(read) WORK.TEMPLAT(UPDATE) 
         SASUSER.TEMPLAT(READ) SASHELP.TMPLMST(READ);
```

When I run a SAS 9.2 session on the server I can see that the template store from my library is added to the ODS path as expected.
However, when I start a session from Enterprise Guide 4.2 the ODS path is still the default path. I know the session has included the autoexec_usermods.sas because libraries that are defined there are available in my session.

I suspect that Enterprise Guide runs some code in the background when starting a session that resets or defines the ODS path to the default path. I found a macros.sas in C:\Program Files\SAS\Shared Files\Images which contains a ODS TMPLPATH statement but the path defined here is also different from the default. So my guess is this is not the correct file or there is other code executed somewhere.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this statement to the SAS Enterprise Guide options to guarantee that it is submitted when you connect to your SAS server.  You can find the option under:

Tools->Options->SAS Programs: "Submit code when connecting to SAS server"
Check the box and add the code that you want to run.

More information at:
http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tips:Project_Specific_Autoexecs_in_Enterprise_Guide